# How to save an online csv file to your computer using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I want to save an online csv file to my computer using pandas. Kindly help out.

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd

url = "https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/data/csv/airtravel.csv"
df = pd.DataFrame(url)
df.to_csv(r"C:\Users\hp\Documents\files.csv")"
```

This is the bug I get:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-8d02ffbff077> in <module>
      2 
      3 url = "https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/data/csv/airtravel.csv"
----> 4 df = pd.DataFrame(url)
      5 df.to_csv(r"C:\Users\hp\Documents\files.csv")
      6 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __init__(self, data, index, columns, dtype, copy)
    483                 )
    484             else:
--> 485                 raise ValueError("DataFrame constructor not properly called!")
    486 
    487         NDFrame.__init__(self, mgr, fastpath=True)

ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `pd.read_csv()` function rather than creating a dataframe by using `pd.DataFrame()`. The latter will only create a dataframe when instantiated from a certain data structure like an array or dictionary.

The first will read the dataframe from your URL.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
url = pd.read_csv("https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/data/csv/airtravel.csv")
df = pd.DataFrame(url)
display(url)
```

---

Or you can read URL as string

```
import io
import requests

url="https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/data/csv/airtravel.csv"
string = requests.get(url).content
data = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(string.decode('utf-8')))
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
display(df)
```

output

```
Month   "1958"  "1959"  "1960"
0   JAN     340     360     417
1   FEB     318     342     391
2   MAR     362     406     419
3   APR     348     396     461
4   MAY     363     420     472
5   JUN     435     472     535
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
import pandas as pd

url = "https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/data/csv/airtravel.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(url)
df.to_csv(r"C:\Users\hp\Documents\files.csv")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

url = "https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/data/csv/airtravel.csv"
path = "test_csv.csv"

pd.read_csv(url).to_csv(path)
```